# Set UILabel from function: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have this code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
ViewController().changeLabel()
```

In my `ViewController.swift` I have this code:

```
    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        myLabel.text = "Hello, I'm in viewDidLoad."
    }
    func changeLabel() {
        print("I'm the test.")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, I'm in printSomething."
    }
```

`myLabel.text = "Hello, I'm in viewDidLoad."` in `viewDidLoad()` is working. `print("I'm the test.")` in `changeLabel()` is also working.

But for `myLabel.text = "Hello, I'm in printSomething."` in `changeLabel()` I'm always getting the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Why is that working in `viewDidLoad()` but not in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
ViewController()
```

means a new VC created on the fly , as you have to load it like

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiate ///////
```

because it's inside the storyboard , your above code only valid if the vc is created programmatically , so you have to make any modifications inside say `viewDidLoad` , but if you have to , you can use this code inside dispatch after

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
   let vc = self.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
   vc.changeLabel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `UILabel` is define in Storyboard nib file, It's won't be load and get connect with View Controller if you call `ViewController().changeLabel()`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //"Main" your storyboard name
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewIdentifier") //Replace viewIdentifier with your view controller's identifier
vc.changeLabel()
```

Comment: this will crash also as the VC is not yet loaded to call **changeLabel** which contains **myLabel.text** where **myLabel** is **nil** at that moment